# How to rename the labels that appear outside of the ctable output [summarytools]

Tags: r, summarytools

I am trying to play around with the formatting of the labels in summarytools::ctable with no luck.

*I would like to keep the longer version of the question name on top of the table, and the shorter version of the question name inside the table (or removed altogether).*

###### Example of long var names

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(summarytools)

mtcars %<>% rename(really_long_variable_name_for_vs = vs, 
                   really_long_variable_name_for_gear = gear)
```

###### If I wanted xtabs of vs and gear with the the new longer names

```
ctable(mtcars$really_long_variable_name_for_gear,mtcars$really_long_variable_name_for_vs)
```

###### To specify shorter names I can use dnn

```
ctable(mtcars$really_long_variable_name_for_gear,mtcars$really_long_variable_name_for_vs,dnn = c('gear short', 'vs short'))
```

[image]

---

But I want the SHORT version of the name to appear inside the table (or not at all)
And the LONG version of the var name to appear outside the table

**Desired output:**

[image]

I tried playing around with the options -- but no luck:

```
ctable(mtcars$gear,mtcars$really_long_variable_name_for_vs, 
       omit_headings = TRUE,
       display.labels = FALSE,
       dfSummary.labels.col = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

In principle, you would use the print method to do that, modifying the Row.variable and Col.variable attributes. However, I realize it's not been correctly implemented. So what you can do is modify the Row.x.Col attribute directly (not documented):

```
ct <- ctable(...)
attr(ct, "data_info")$Row.x.Col <- "long_variable_name * other_long_variable_name"
```